# Entity Framework Code First Migrations: get sql scripts programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

I am implementing Entity Framework (v5) Code-Based Migrations for my project.

The db admins from our clients are sometimes a little bit paranoid and want to execute the sql scripts by hand.

Since we have got already many versions and we support SqlServer and Oracle parallel, we don't want to administer several update scripts from all possible versions x.x.x.x to y.y.y.y. Is it not possible to get programmatically the sql script in the same way as I call it in the Package Manager Console

```
Update-Database -Script
```

So the client would get via a simple console application depending his db system and current version the correct sql script as output.

Comment: what or where is the problem for me it is not clear?

Comment: I can call `Update-Database` from my Visual Studio Console, but I would like to call it through source code. So the client can execute a small application that generates the sql dynamically.

Comment: You need for that a DBMigrator I will make an example for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  var configuration = new Configuration();
  var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

  var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
  var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);
  Console.WriteLine(script);

  migrator.Update();

  var pending = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
```

more info:
http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/02/15/using-entity-framework-4-3-database-migration-for-any-project.aspx

---

basically you need

```
DbMigrator db = new DbMigrator(HERE CONNECTION STRING);
db.Update(HERE TARGET VERSION);
```